# Is there a way to change directories in DBT cloud

Tags: dbt

Is there a good/accepted way to change directories in DBT cloud? Currently DBT cloud pulls from the main branch of my repo and then uses the top level folder for where it looks for the dbt_project.yml file.

I was hoping to have that file in a subfolder like src/dbt and have DBT cloud recognize it. Was wondering if anyone else ran into this issue. I have no issues running DBT locally but was hoping to develop on cloud.

Comment: Can you share how your directory and project.yml is currently setup? Do you have to use any special options to run via the CLI locally?

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to your project settings in dbt Cloud and set *DBT PROJECT SUBDIRECTORY* under *Overview*.